# need help understanding tf

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay I now need help understanding the role of transforms in the navigation stack. I have a simple transform publisher up and running but the tutorials  for the navigation library do not explain well what exactly is to be used for and where it is being published too.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/80131/need-help-understanding-tf/) by [Massbuilder](https://answers.ros.org/users/6726/massbuilder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2013-09-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Basically it's up to you how you name your frames as everything is configurable. There are some standard names for frames that are usually set as defaults: http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html That document also explains the semantics of those frames.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1